# How do I adjust a Blum 170° face frame hinge?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, hinges

My parents have some cabinets in their kitchen and the door suddenly stopped closing. It seems the bottom hinge is the issue. I tried adjusting it following [this PDF](https://go.rockler.com/tech/blum-170-deg-face-frame-hinge-instructions.pdf) but it still just won’t close. I’ve added some photos of the door and hinge

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably more in the DIY.SE wheelhouse. Though, honestly: replace the hinge. They aren't _really_ user-serviceable, not that I haven't tried.

Comment: @jdv darn :/ but okay awesome thanks. I’m normally just a StackOverflow user so don’t know entirely where to post other questions all the time! :)

Comment: Still, welcome to WW.SE! There is a fair amount of overlap with DIY.SE here, but most here will want Q&A specifically about power and hand tools working wood. So a Q about _making_ those cupboards would probably be satisfactory. But a Q about fixing a busted hinge is probably going to be considered off-topic here.

Comment: Somewhere near the middle of the plate that attaches it to the cabinet, there's a screw on the main part of the hinge. Loosen it; pull the whole door forward and re-tighten that screw. Probably do that up top. Report back.

Comment: If you do ask this on DIY could you please link to the Q here in a Comment? I'll be interested to see if more than one Answer, or a consensus view, is to get a new hinge. jdv and I are often on the same page about things but that would not have been my first recommendation. I've poked and prodded and tweaked kitchen-cupboard hinges many many times and IME one of the things to try before you write the hinge off as unadjustable or broken is *taking the door off*.